# Calling virtual method from virtual destructor in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, destructor

I want to destruct an object of class `B`.

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "construct A" << av::endl;
        a = new int;
    }
    virtual ~A() {
        std::cout << "destruct A" << av::endl;
        this->clear();
    }
    virtual void clear() {
        std::cout << "clear A" << av::endl;
        delete a;
    }
protected:
    int *a;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {
        std::cout << "construct B" << av::endl;
        b = new int;
    }
    ~B() {
        std::cout << "destruct B" << av::endl;
    }
    void clear() override {
        std::cout << "clear B" << av::endl;
        delete b;
        delete this->a;
    }
private:
    int *b;
};
```

And I want it to be done with `clear()` method. But when I execute following code:

```
A *a = new B();
delete a;
```

I get:

> construct A construct B destruct B destruct A clear A

And `clear B` is never printed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Informally, In `~A();` the B part is already destroyed, calling any function of B doesn't make any sense.

---

Effective C++ Item 9: Never call virtual functions during construction or destruction.

> Once a derived class destructor has run, the object’s derived class
>   data members assume undefined values, so C++ treats them as if they no
>   longer exist. Upon entry to the base class destructor, the object
>   becomes a base class object, and all parts of C++ — virtual functions,
>   dynamic_cast s, etc., —treat it that way.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning "Effective C++", I guess its time for me to run through it again.